# C++- How to increase stack size to allow more recursion for Kosaraju's Algorithm to compute Strongly Connected Components

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am using a mac, 4GB of RAM and CLion IDE. Compiler is Clang. I need to allow more recursion in this recursive implementation of Depth First Search (currently fails on a graph with 80k nodes).

```
typedef unordered_map <int, vector<int>> graph;
void DFS (graph &G, int i, vector <bool> &visited) {

    visited[i] = true;
    for (int j = 0; i < G[i].size(); j++) {
        if (!visited[G[i][j]]) {
            DFS(G, G[i][j], visited);
        }
    }
    t++;
    finishingTime[t] = i; //important step
}
```

This is for an implementation of Kosaraju's algorithm to compute strongly connected components in a graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm I know it is possible to implement DFS as iterative instead but the last step is important, and I can't find a way to include it using iteration. This is because that step is done when DFS fails and backtracking occurs, and recursion provides a very natural way to do this.

So currently I have only two options:

- Increase the stack size to allow more recursion
- Or find an iterative solution

Any ideas how to do either?

Comment: _"Or find an iterative solution"_ You can always use a `std::stack` instead of recursion.

Comment: Increasing the stack size is only postponing the problem :)

Comment: Did you even read my question? :P I know there is an iterative DFS implementation but it doesn't work with Kosaraju's algorithm as it is. Need to make some modification to record when backtracking takes place.

Comment: (Shouldn't that read `finishingTime[i] = t;`? `//important step` is an appalling comment - describe _what_ some piece of code _is to accomplish - if_ you can't make it blatantly obvious.)

Comment: @greybeard I don't think I need to make it blatantly obvious. The issue is just that I need to keep track of when the backtracking occurs, not why. To make it so, I would have to post the rest of my code for the algorithm as well, but which is not required.

Comment: (I'm perfectly comfortable with _not_ everything included in an SO post, as with some code presented being not obvious. You put the motivation to include the keeping of "step-number" _t_ with some index _i_ not in the code itself (as a comment), and it looks off that something named _xyzTime_ is indexed by a _t_ and assigned an index _i_ used as an "index" before. (Code _does_ get separated from any accompanying material - even header comments are at risk.))

Comment: Very easy to make that iterative with stl. Just create a stack, and push the root.  Then, while the stack is not empty, pop the first element, iterate over the children in reverse (probably unnecessary, but keep behaviour the same), and push them if unvisited, then set finishing time and pop the next element.

Comment: @Rad Lexus That's very much a partial truth. Stack size is pretty limited, heap size goes up to several billion bytes even on a  fairly normal desktop. Eventually this sort of brute force algorithm will fail, and the fact that is blowing the stack is a sign that it might be the wrong approach, but without seeing the whole problem we can't comment on that.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I understand your idea, but I have tried the iterative solution, just that it sometimes misses my function. Lets say I move over a node 2 to nodes 4 and 5 both of which are leaves. I need to set a value of finishing time to 2, but which will get missed in the iterative implementation of DFS.

Comment: Let's see. Have I missed something or does my code have the same effect? (Answer posted)

Comment: Besides using a std::stack<> to avoid stack overflow, you may use a more compact data structure for representing your graph, there is a significant overhead with STL classes that becomes terrible when nesting them (unorder_map<vector<T>>), you may consider instead using "compressed row storage" sparse matrix representation, performance gain in both space and time will be very significative as compared to unorder_map<vector<T>>.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by a comment you can put each call to DFS on a stack allocated on heap made from the parameter list of DFS and then iterate through the stack. Each entry in the stack is essentially a task.

Pseudo-like code:

```
Start and run "recursion":
nr_of_recursions = 0;
dfs_task_stack.push(first_task_params)
while dfs_task_stack not empty
  DFS(dfs_task_stack.pop)
  nr_of_recursions += 1
end while;
true_finishingtime[] = nr_of_recursions - finishingtime[];

DFS:
for each recursion found
  dfs_task_stack.push(task_params)
end for;
t++; finishingtime...
```

Not sure of your algorithm but it may be significant which order you push your tasks to the stack, i.e. the order of "for each ...".

I took the liberty of redefining the meaning of "finishingtime" to its inverse. To get the original definition substract the new finishingtime with the total number of recursions made.

Comment: What is "task_stack"?

Comment: @SinByCos A stack of DFS function calls built from its parameters. I think the full c++ declaration would be std::stack<G, int, std::vector<bool>> task_stack; which matches you parameter list in DFS. However since both graph and visited are "global" for any recursion it would suffice with std::stack<int> and pass the globals in the while-loop scope.

Comment: Oh, okay think I got it. And how should I implement "for each recursion found" ?

Comment: @SinByCos Like the original code, but swap DFS(...) with dfs_task_stack.push(G[i][j]). You need to flip the loop order from bottom-up to top-down to get the same result as before, but I´m honestly not sure whether or not this is significant for the algorithm.

Comment: @SinByCos Feel free to edit my answer with your solution so I may review it.

Comment: Not sure how this will work though. I need the step "finishingtime..." only to occur when I backtrack, which is only when I reach a node from where there are no adjacent nodes, or I've visited all the adj nodes

Comment: @SinByCos I see. I would "invert" the definition of finishing time. What you would need to do is save the last "i" in the algorithm and negate any finishingtime with it: true_finish = last_i - finishing_time. Will edit to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but you can build the list of finished times using just a stack and a visited state array, by having more than one visited state.

The following code is just to illustrate the algorithm. I didn't actually tested it a lot (just a little `{{0, {1}}, {1, <>}, {2, <>}}` small test) but I already used this technique in the very same way in the past for bigger graphs and I know it works.

The idea is to keep the visited node in the stack after it's being visited until all visited before it are pop, thus emulating the recursive call but with less data pushed and in a stack object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <cassert>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef enum {
    vssClean,
    vssPushed,
    vssVisited
} VerticeStackState;


typedef unordered_map <int, vector<int>> graph;
void kosarajuBuildFinishOrder(const int inital, graph &G, vector<int> &finish, vector<VerticeStackState> &state, int &lastFinished) {

    assert(vssClean == state[inital]);



    std::stack<int> stack;

    stack.push(inital);
    state[inital] = vssPushed;

    int current;
    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        current = stack.top();
        if (vssPushed == state[current])
        {
            state[current] = vssVisited;
            for (const auto to: G[current])
            {
                if (state[to]==vssClean)
                {
                    state[to] = vssPushed;
                    stack.push(to);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            assert(vssVisited == state[current]);
            stack.pop();
            finish[--lastFinished] = current;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    graph G;
    G.insert({0, vector<int>(1, 1)});
    G.insert({1, vector<int>()});
    G.insert({2, vector<int>()});

    vector<int> finish(G.size(), 0);
    vector <VerticeStackState> state(G.size(), vssClean);


    int  lastFinished = G.size();

    for (int i=0; i < G.size(); ++i) {
        if (vssClean == state[i]){
            kosarajuBuildFinishOrder(i, G, finish, state, lastFinished);
        }
    }

    for (auto i: finish) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one of the options you mentioned about increasing the stack size, you can do as such:

```
g++ -Wl,--stack,16777216 -o kosaraju.exe kosaraju_stl.cpp
```

This increases the stack size to 16MiB. While as mentioned in earlier answers, it's just postponing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef unordered_map <int, vector<int>> graph;
void DFS (graph &G, vector <bool> &visited) {

std::stack<int> stack;
stack.push(0);  // root 
int i, j;

while(!stack.empty())
{
    i = stack.pop_back();
    visited[i] = true;
    for (j= (int) G[i].size() -1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        if (!visited[G[i][j]]) 
        {
            stack.push_back(G[i][j]);

        }
    }
    t++;
    finishingTime[t] = i; //important step
  } // end while.
 }
```

Anyone can make a programming error and since I don't have your test data I can't test this, but is output the same?

Comment: No it won't work. It will assign the finishing time to the root node as 1, whereas the node who's finishing time is 1 should be the first node encountered of which there are no non-visited adjacent nodes.